# Accessing Ruby on Rails app from a Remote PC/Network - Windows 7 WEBrick

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am making an app using Rails on my home pc, and need to access the page from a computer at work.

I've found a few questions relating to this, but nothing like a process which I can follow as someone who doesn't have an awful lot of networking experience.

I know I need to open the port which I am using, but I can't seem to do this, as in windows firewall/allow programs I cant see the 'add port' button...

Am I right in thinking that the server should be set up to use default gateway as the IP ($bin/ rails server -p 192.168.0.1), and then use my public IP to access it from my work PC?

Any help/guidance is much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Follow one of the port forwarding tutorials which are easily found online.

The IP you set up which looks like **192.168.0.12** or similar is the local IP address. Use this too access the website on the home network: **192.168.0.12:3000** if you forwarded port 3000.

$/bin/ rails s -b 192.168.0.12 -p 3000

Now, to access the server from external network, navigate to: **http://your.public.ip.address:3000**, which can be found by searching "what is my ip address" in Google.

Answer (score 1):

There are some projects/software that help the job easier:

- https://ngrok.com
- http://localtunnel.me
- http://proxylocal.com